# Does changing the return type of a function for a child type breaks binary compatibility?

Tags: c#, inheritance, binary-compatibility

Let's go straight to it :

Old code :

```
public interface IFoo {}
public class Foo : IFoo {}
...
public static IFoo Bar() { return new Foo(); }
```

New code :

```
public static Foo Bar() { return new Foo(); }
```

Obviously there should be no problem here, everything you were doing on the old return type, you can still do on the new return type, any `is`, `as` or cast should behave the same as before...

So did I break binary compatibility, or can I just release it as a minor version without bothering users ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This breaks binary compatibility, but not (most) compile-time compatibility issues, so it's typically an easy migration.

Note that it can even be a compile-time break if the client code constructs a delegate from the method.

Comment: To be explicit, if some consumer of the code has written `Func<IFoo> f = TheType.Bar;` where `TheType` is the name of the asker's class, that would break.

Comment: Actually I don't think my example (comment above) is correct. It would be correct if `Foo` were a `struct`, but it is a `class`. Actually I can't come up with an example. Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

You could have problems with people who have created unit tests around your code. Because it's static people could have created a FooAdapater as follows:-

```
public class FooAdapater(){ 
public IFoo GetFoo() { Return your static Bar; }
}
```

They could then create a mocked foo adapter than returns a mocked foo. Your code would break this scenario.

So, no it's not binary compatible :-)

Comment: This wouldn't affect his direct type, as this is a static method (not overridable) within a class or struct...